# Can't connect to netgear N750 router used as bridge for FiOS router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

A long time ago I set up my netgear router as a bridge for my main router, using some ethernet cables and ethernet-over-power adapters. I set the netgear router's ip to 192.168.1.2 so it wouldn't conflict with the main router, and the set up works fine.

The problem is, I want to go in and edit the settings, and I can't do that.

- I've tried going to 192.168.1.2, and all I get is a blank page. When I went to 192.168.1.1, it goes to my FiOS router, as expected.
- I tried unplugging the bridged router from the main router and attempting to connect again (over ethernet to the bridged router) and I still get "can't reach 192.168.1.2" or a blank page.

Does anyone know a way to get into my netgear router that won't involve resetting it and starting from scratch?

Comment: Why not enable the routing functionality in the N750 and set up a route between the N750 and the FiOS?

Comment: How would I do that? And what exactly does that mean? I can still connect to my router wirelessly, if that's what you mean by routing functionality. But if that's not it and I have to do something else in the settings, that would mean resetting the router first and starting over, which I'd rather not do

Comment: Most SoHo routers/access_point/switch/firewall-combo devices do not listen to their admin page on the WAN facing connection. Are you sure you are reaching it via the LAN side and not the WAM side (e.g. try it with a wired cable directly plugged into a LAN port on the N750).

Comment: I haven't tried in a long time, but when I did I tried both through a laptop connected wirelessly and my desktop that was plugged into the router. Is there a way I can scan the assigned addresses and see which one is a router?